# How do I create an event listener without using a feature?

Tags: event-handlers

I want to create an event listener for SharePoint.
I need to do that without using a feature.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple console application to do this or [use an existing tool](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1547).

The EventReceivers property on a list can be used to add new ones. There is an example [in this post](http://www.walisystems.com/articles/sps/moss-surveys/eventhandler/writing-an-event-handler-for-a-survey.htm).

[More on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=EventReceivers.Add).